# Alternative of Kibana for the advanced aggregation graph/table

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have been struggling a lot in the past due to the limited plots and limited aggregation(kibana 4 beta 2) in the `kibana`. 
I wanted to "convert `select sum(Col1 + Col2), Col3 from Table group by Col3 Order by Col3 desc`". I was able to convert the above query in the json request form. But i couldn't translate it to the Graphical representation or In the Aggregated Table.

So, could you please suggest alternatives of the `kibana` in which these kind of queries or custom json reqeust can be represented?